# Entity Systems in C++

Tags: c++, game-engine

In game development there is a notion of Entity System which is aiming to simplify the game loop by gaining a flexible architecture. For details see the links below:

http://www.richardlord.net/blog/what-is-an-entity-framework
http://shaun.boyblack.co.za/blog/2012/08/04/games-and-entity-systems/

Now I wonder how it is possible to realize automatic `Node` creation when a `Component` is added to an `Entity` in C++? Please tell me the principle of identifying what `Nodes` can be spawned from a specific `Entity`, i.e. you should have list of `Component` and classes that aggregate components. And you should understand what classes can be created with the list of data.

For example I have `Components`:

```
class PositionComponent
{
  int m_x;
  int m_y;
  int m_rotation;
};

class VelocityComponent
{
  int m_vX;
  int m_vY;
  int m_vAngular;
};

class RenderableComponent
{
  Sprite m_view;
};
```

And nodes:

```
class MoveNode
{
  PositionComponent m_position;
  VelocityComponent m_velocity;
};

class RenderNode
{
  RenderableComponent m_rend;
  PositionComponent m_position;
};
```

Now if I create an `Entity` like this:

```
Entity * e = new Entity;
e.add(new PositionComponent);
e.add(new VelocityComponent);
```

Then I want to have a code that creates a `MoveNode` automatically, and if I add also this:

```
e.add(new RenderableComponent);
```

Then I want to know that also `RenderNode` is created. Consequently, when I delete it:

e.remove(new RenderableComponent);

the `RenderNode` should be deleted. And this process, of course, should not be bind to the specific `Nodes` and `Components` I have defined.

How is it possible to realize this in C++?

Comment: Did you really mean to tag [tag:entity-framework] for what's described there, or is the link you have given a different pair of shoes?

Comment: This frameworks are called Entity Frameworks. But I guess there is a framework, called like that. If it is so, then oops! :)

Comment: The tag's wiki entry explicitly refers to ADO .NET, doubt you're really referring to this here. May be better just to remove the tag, to reach  a broader audience for your question.

Comment: well i do not see any benefit from this approach it actually complicate things but it can be done (virtual component must have pointers or list of pointers to any possible subcomponent and the presence can be detected by nonzero address or some flag. but opretion with such classes is horrible !!!

Answer (score 17):

I am slightly confused, since it appears to mix concepts. I will try to shed some light on the two concepts.

### Entity & Component

The entity component system is quite common in game engines, for example Unity implements it quite visibly. It tries to address the issue that simple inheritance does not work well in many cases, such as mixing rendering and collision information; is a `Collidable` also a `Renderable`? And since multiple inheritance is a scary thing for many and not supported in many languages, the only way out of this is the Entity/Component design. *(Actually not the only solution, but that is a different issue.)*

The design for entity component is quite simple, you have a class `Entity` that takes multiple objects of type `Component`. There will be multiple components that "do" something, like a `MeshRenderer`, `TriMeshCollision` or `RigidBodyMotion`. As stated in the articles, the actual logic does not need to be implemented in the components themselves. The component just "flags" the entity for specific logic. It makes sense to delegate the actual work to be done in a tight loop in a system, maybe even in a different thread, but more to that later.

Then the actual entity is composed. There are two basic ways to do this, in code or in data.

For example you compose objects in code that represent one "real world" object; the object of type `Goblin` exists and it is derived from the class `Entity`. The constructor from `Goblin` will then create all components and register them on itself. Inheritance is now only done for high level logic, for example the `FastGoblin` is derived from `Goblin` and only has a different material and speed setting.

The second way to create objects is through data, that is you have some form of object description language. (Take something in XML or JSON) This will then create in a factory method something based on a given template in that is defined in this object description language.

### Node Based Work Scheduling

It may make sense to have objects that are fully defined, but the logic not being executed. Think about objects on the server or in the editor. On the server you do not want the rendering code to be in the way. So the basic approach is to create components that contain no data. The problem to solve is, how do you efficiently get things done without iterating through the entire scene each frame and typecasting the objects around?

What your second link describes is basically a botched version of [Designing the Framework of a Parallel Game Engine](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/designing-the-framework-of-a-parallel-game-engine)

There needs to be a way to schedule the work in an efficient way. The proposed solution is to have "nodes" that each do a specific task. The nodes are then scheduled, by submitting them to either a work scheduler or a specific system.

Take for example rendering. You have an entity and it has a `MeshRenderer` component. This component will create a `RenderNode` and submit it to the `RenderSystem`. Then when it is time to render the frame the `RenderSystem` will simply iterate over each `RenderNode` and call its display method. In the display method the actual rendering is done.

Alternatively the system, engine or entity can create nodes based on specific component configurations. Take for example physics. The Entity has the `TriMeshCollision` and `RigidBodyMovement` components. The `PhysicsSystem` seeing this configuration creates a `RigidBodyNode` that takes the two components as inputs and thus implements rigid body motion. Should the entity only have a `TriMeshCollision` component the `PhysicsSystem` would then create a `StaticColliderNode` to implement the behavior.

But like the construction mechanic for components from data, the nodes can also be created and attached to the entity through a factory function. This can be part of either the object definition or a rule based system.

Mapping this design into C++ should be straight forward. The rather difficult bit is to figure out a way how the different bits get connected; for example, how the `MeshRenderer` gets access to the `RenderSystem` so it can submit its `RenderNode`. But this can be solved with a singleton *(shudder)* or by passing a `Game`/`Engine` object around at the construction of the `Entity` or `Component`.

### Is this good design?

But the issue I want to address here is: **Is this good design?**

I have troubles with your second link *(Games And Entity Systems)*, since I think the design will fall flat on its nose quite quickly. This is true for other aspects like physics, but this will become quite inefficient when considering modern 3D rendering.

When you need to organize the scene spatially to efficiently cull hidden objects, organize the objects into batches for lighting and reduce resource switching then the entire "list of nodes" concepts is moot since you need a separate organisational structure anyway.

At this point you can let the components "talk" directly to the systems and each system has its own unique specific API that is fit for its specific purpose. The requirements of rendering, sound and input are each significantly different and tying to cram them into on API is futile.

### See Also

- [Entity/Component based engine rendering separation from logic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50531/entity-component-based-engine-rendering-separation-from-logic)

Comment: Thank you for detailed analysis, but I have asked here how to implement the automatic node creation in c++ for Entity Systems. I guess this does not answer my question. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Does this not solve your problem: "You have an entity and it has a MeshRenderer component. This component will create a RenderNode and submit it to the RenderSystem." There is nothing automatic, the node is bound to the component in that they two belong sort of together. The component will simply create the node, for example with new.

Comment: A Node should be a composition of multiple components in general. In this case I don't understand how the Component can create a Node.

Comment: I reread the relevant section of "Games And Entity Systems" and in that case basically you need to affix the node "from the outside". This would be done in the derived class, i.e. Goblin, or the factory method. An entity is defined not only by the component but the nodes. Alternatively either systems or the engine can detect specific component compositions and generate the appropriate nodes. (I will amend the answer to reflect this.)

Comment: The idea is that the Engine should detect and create appropriate nodes. But How it can be done in C++, this is my question :)

Comment: I don't think that each specific system should create the nodes  and add it to the engine. I think this work should do the engine itself, so that we could rely on the process on Framework code. I mean   if we create an Entity System framework, the framework should take care of Node creation and not the framework user who create specific Systems. What you think?

Comment: Whatever suites your need. There is not one definite answer... I personally think the Entity/Component in general and the "Games And Entity Systems" in specific are over-engineering the problem. There are approaches are more compacter and more efficient than that.

Comment: rioki please tell me an example of other approach. I need to read them, please!

Comment: Model-View-Controller, Document-View, Scene-Graph, Binary-Space-Partition are some search terms you can feed into Google. It basically boils down to plain old software engineering, the underlying architectural problems are no different from a word processor than a game engine. Start building something small and simple and then scale that up where it starts to hurt. Over engineering a problem is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you so much, about MVC I know, but the other I will investigate with pleasure.